# Log commits added to master in last 24 hours

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to show commits (excluding merge commits) which were added to the `master` branch in the last 24 hours. Currently i am using this command for that:

```
git log --format=format:%s --no-merges --since='24 hours ago'
```

However this has a problem: if a commit is older than 24 hours, but merged into the `master` branch in the last 24 hours, the command will not list the commit. Is it possible to show commits added to the `master` branch in last 24 hours, and not commits created in last 24 hours?

Please note i execute this in a clean CI workspace, so `git reflog` cannot help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `--no-merges`, might `--first-parent` work better?

Comment: @ams that would only show the merge commits. I need the not merged commits, added to the `master` branch in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `rev-list` is what you want.

Try this:

```
git rev-list --no-merges '^<24-hour-old-commit>' HEAD
```

That should list all the non-merge commits that are reachable from commit `HEAD`, but not reachable from from commit `<24-hour-old-commit>`.

For example, in this revision graph, it'll list the upper case commits, but not lower case:

```
a - b - c - 24h - H - i - J - K - HEAD
     \               /
      D - E - F - G '
```

Commits `H`, `J`, `K`, and `HEAD` are all younger than 24 hours old. Commit `i` is also younger, but is omitted as it is a merge commit. Commits `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G` may be any age, but have only been merged within the last 24 hours, so they are listed also.

---

Within the above command, `--max-age` or `--since` options will have the same problem as you have with `git log`, but they can be used to find `<24-hour-old-commit>` for you:

```
git rev-list -n1 --before="24 hours" --first-parent HEAD
```

That is, "give only 1 commit ID, that must be at least 24 hours old, and is on the current branch".

Putting it all together:

```
git rev-list --no-merges HEAD \
             --not $(git rev-list -n1 --before="24 hours" --first-parent HEAD)
```

(Note: `--not abcdef` is another way to say `^abcdef` except that it applies to *all* following arguments, hence reordering the options.)

The default output of `rev-list` is just raw revisions, but you can make it more like `git log` using the `--pretty` option. `--pretty=short` is approximately the same as you're used to.

Comment: but it wouldn't be hard to script - currently i have no idea how, this is where i also stuck. Would you mind elaborating? I think this is a tricky task, we have to find the first commit added to `master` in the last 24 hours...

Comment: I was just looking that up. Edit soon. :-)

Comment: Info added, please test and report back. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this shows really old commits too, added 4 days ago.

Comment: That's expected if they're on a branch that was only just merged today.

Comment: I added a picture and some words to show what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, they were not merged today, but 4 days ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92473/discussion-between-ams-and-wondercsabo).

Comment: The problems with the original answer were resolved, and the answer has now been updated.